# Check if query exists in MS Access DB from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check if a query name exists in an Access DB...from Excel.

I've found lots of ways to do it from within Access, but nothing from Excel.  I'd prefer to have it use late binding.

I'm currently making a connection to the DB and then trying to open a recordset with a SQL string...if the Query doesn't exist, there is an error popup

`Run-time error '-2147217900(80040e14)': Syntax error in FROM clause.`

Either I need to be able to capture that error without user interaction...I tried adding `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before hand, but that didn't stop the popup...OR I need to be able to check the DB for that Query name.

I have an `On Error GoTo` statement at the start of the function, but that never gets triggered because the pop up only allows to End or Debug...I don't want Users to be able to debug...they have no idea what they are doing...or this error wouldn't have happened in the first place.  And if they End, well...the error doesn't get fixed and the workbook blows up.

I've tried this as well...

```
Dim rs As Object, oCon As Object, db As Object, qdf As Object
Dim wsImport As Worksheet
Dim sSQL As String
On Error GoTo Err_VQ

  Set wsImport = Sheets("Import")
  Set oCon = MakeConnection
  Set db = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120").OpenDatabase(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DB.accdb")
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Set qdf = db.querydefs(wsImport.[H1]) '<---- Run time error on this line
  'wsImport.[H1] contains the query name
```

But I still get a pop up for `run time error 3265 Item not Found in Collection`...which is fine...but how do I suppress the pop up?

**EDIT -** By 'fine' I mean that is the error I would expect since the query name doesn't exist...but I need to know how to suppress the error and work with it inside of the code.

Comment: I think if your code contains this line `On Error GoTo Err_VQ`, vba will not show any error pop up if your sub has `Err_VQ:` Label.

Comment: It has the label...still get the pop up.

Comment: in VBE Tools>Options > General > Error Trapping, and choose: `Break on Unhandled Errors`.

Comment: Just loop through the `QueryDefs` looking for a match instead of immediately indexing into it.

Comment: Break on unhandled errors was it!  I forgot I had that on to catch a different error yesterday.